Auto boot on preseed UEFI Debian 12 image
I'm used to preseed my Debian images since years on Legacy BIOS mode. Now we have to move to UEFI standards and i'm having some small issues. This post is about Debian 12 preseeding.
On a Legacy BIOS mode, I did the following steps to allow automatic boot (no need to press enter in the boot menu) on my preseed instructions :

Modify the append line of /isolinux/gtk.cfg to allow automatic boot using preseed.cfg

default installgui
label installgui
        menu label ^Graphical install
        menu default
        kernel /install.amd/vmlinuz
        append auto=true priority=critical vga=788 initrd=/install.amd/gtk/initrd.gz preseed/file=/cdrom/preseed.cfg --- quiet


Modify timeout from 0 to 1 on /isolinux.isolinux.cfg, this step allow to almost immediately boot

path
prompt 0
timeout 1
include menu.cfg
default vesamenu.c32

Result was : if i boot on my preseed ISO, I just had to watch , absolutely no human action.
Now let's talk about UEFI. I've already change my preseed.cfg to configure EFI partitioning. At the moment my preseed.cfg is perfectly working, if I launch it manually from the boot menu everything is fine.
My current issue is : When I boot my UEFI preseeded ISO, it's stuck on the Installation Menu so I have to manually select and press Enter on Graphical Install or Install
I read on this post that I had to add parameters in grub.cfg, test it to append at the bottom of the file but nothing has changed.
In UEFI mode within isolinux, what is accountable for boot options and boot menu ?
EDIT 17-07-2024:
Finally found a workaround by modifying only grub.cfg this way :

add set timeout=2 at the bottom of the file
at the Graphical Install entry menu, change the linux instruction to :
linux    /install.amd/vmlinuz preseed/file=/cdrom/preseed.cfg auto=true priority=critical vga=788 --- quiet 

Everything is working great now.

Sorry for answering a question with another, but I don't get my own ISO to boot, so may you please share how you created it? I am trying to build a Debian 12 net install ISO with integrated preseed file.

If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the Ask Question button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - From Review
